# How can I run Plant vs Zombies in a resizable window mode?

Tags: pc, steam, plants-vs-zombies

I would like to play Plant vs Zombies in window mode but the result is a window too small for my actual resolution (1920x1200).

Is it possible, using some external program and without changing my native desktop resolution, to launch Plant vs Zombies in a sizable/stretchable window?

Comment: I read it "How can I ruin Plants vs (etc)".... Lol

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit overboard, but you could do like the accepted answer on this question: [Is it possible to run RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 in windowed mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/is-it-possible-to-run-rollercoaster-tycoon-2-in-windowed-mode)

You could install Virtual PC on Windows 7, install and run PvZ on that, and then size it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use software such as [ResizeEnable](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ResizeEnable/) to make the window resizable, although I can't vouch for the quality of this specific product, having not used it.

If there's a settings.ini file or something similar somewhere in your PvZ folder, you might be able to change the default size of the windowed application as well.

Comment: I tried ResizeEnable but it doesn't work, at least on my OS (Windows 7 32-bit).

Answer (score 1):

Plants vs Zombies has a fixed resolution of 800*600, so you won't be able to do this unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Plants Vs. Zombies' Windowed Mode runs the game at 800x600. You can access the windowed game by unchecking the 'Fullscreen' option in the menu here:

[image: In-game menu]

You mentioned that 800x600 is too small for your screen. As a workaround that doesn't require installing additional software, you could temporarily lower your PC's screen resolution.

On Windows 7 and up:

- Right-Click the Desktop
- Click *Screen Resolution*
- Lower your screen resolution and click Apply.

You can also adjust the size of the taskbar to be smaller if you find this takes too much space:

- Right-Click the Taskbar->Properties
- Check the 'Use Small Icons' box
- Apply and OK

This wont make the window resizable, but will make it larger on screen relative to the resolution that the OS is outputting.